# Remove dataclass dependency

Tags: python, python-3.x, cookies, python-dataclasses

I am using Python 3.5 which does not have support for `dataclass`.

Is there a way to convert the following class to work without `dataclasses`?

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Cookie:
    """Models a cookie."""

    domain: str
    flag: bool
    path: str
    secure: bool
    expiry: int
    name: str
    value: str

    def to_dict(self):
        """Returns the cookie as a dictionary.

        Returns:
            cookie (dict): The dictionary with the required values of the cookie

        """
        return {key: getattr(self, key) for key in ('domain', 'name', 'value', 'path')}
```

This is from the [locationsharinglib](https://github.com/costastf/locationsharinglib) repository

Comment: Note that `locationsharinglib` states they only support 3.7 and newer. You may have other issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the code to using [`attrs`](http://www.attrs.org/) (which inspired `dataclasses`) or just write out the class by hand. Given that the project you link to uses the class [purely as a temporary dataholder](https://github.com/costastf/locationsharinglib/blob/bc801d802dcb9d67db7eee79b692085ba94efef3/locationsharinglib/locationsharinglib.py#L136-L139) and not for anything else, writing it out by hand is as simple as:

```
class Cookie:
    """Models a cookie."""
    def __init__(self, domain, flag, path, secure, expiry, name, value):
        self.domain = domain
        self.flag = flag
        self.path = path
        self.secure = secure
        self.expiry = expiry
        self.name = name
        self.value = value

    def to_dict(self):
        """Returns the cookie as a dictionary.
        Returns:
            cookie (dict): The dictionary with the required values of the cookie
        """
        return {key: getattr(self, key) for key in ('domain', 'name', 'value', 'path')}
```

Otherwise, the `attrs` version, avoiding using variable annotations (which are not supported in 3.5):

```
@attr.s
class Cookie:
    """Models a cookie."""

    domain = attr.ib()
    flag = attr.ib()
    path = attr.ib()
    secure = attr.ib()
    expiry = attr.ib()
    name = attr.ib()
    value = attr.ib()

    def to_dict(self):
        """Returns the cookie as a dictionary.
        Returns:
            cookie (dict): The dictionary with the required values of the cookie
        """
        return {key: getattr(self, key) for key in ('domain', 'name', 'value', 'path')}
```

Note, however, that `locationsharinglib` [states in their package metadata](https://github.com/costastf/locationsharinglib/blob/bc801d802dcb9d67db7eee79b692085ba94efef3/setup.py#L49) that they only support Python 3.7, so you may run into other issues with that project.

Comment: Ran `pip install dataclasses` and it installed fine but running `from dataclasses import dataclass` returns Syntax Error for `f'name={self.name!r},'`

Comment: Your solution of `self.X = X` worked beautifully. Just had to remove instances of `dataclass`

Comment: @Bijan: Ah, sorry, I missed that the project only works on 3.6..